# Eloquent Injected Multiple Model Relationships

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.6

So I learned in JeffreyWay's screencasts that I can use Eloquent to get the associated id from a model injected to another model.

I'm following his series about Laravel 5.4.

Here, I have a one-to-many relationships of user to posts.

**App/Post**

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

In my User Model, I have a publish method where the Post Model is injected. The publish method is used to create a post entry into the database.

**App/User**

```
public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
}

public function publish(Post $post)
{
    $this->posts()->save($post);
}
```

I then have a store method in my PostsController that calls the publish method  inside my User Model.

**PostsController**

```
class PostsController extends Controller
{
     public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth')->except(['index', 'show']);
    }

    public function store()
    {
        auth()->user()->publish(
           new Post(request(['title', 'body']))
        );
    }
}
```

When the publish method is called, the injected Post class automatically sets the user_id to the save method.

My question is, how do I make a relationship like this in a situation where for every posts, there are comments. These comments are associated to the Post and the User that created the comment.

In short, I should have both user_id and post_id when I call the addComment method.

Answer (score 0):

**User Model:**

```
public function posts(){
  return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
}

public function comments(){
  return $this->hasMany(Comments::class);
}
```

**Posts Model**

```
public function user(){
  return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

public function comments(){
  return $this->hasMany(Comments::class);
}
```

**Comments Model**

```
public function post(){
  return $this->belongsTo(Post::class);
}

public function user(){
  return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

**Example Problems**:

1) Get user comments:

> Solution: auth()->user()->comments()->get();   <- collection of user
>   comments .

2) Get user from the given comment:

> Solution: Comment::find($someCommentId)->user()->first()->name;  <-
>   User name from a specific comment.

3) Get all comments for a specific post .

> Solution: Post::first()->comments()->get(); or [eager load](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)
>   Post::with('comments')->first();   <- A collection that contains post
>   information within it u can find a collection of comments for that
>   post.

4) Load user when loading a comment:

> Solution: Comment::with('user')->first();  <- single collection
>   containing a collection with user info and comment info.

5) Load a specific user post and comments for that post at the same time:

> Solution: User::with('posts.comments')->first(); <- Contains a
>   collection with user info and collection of all user posts with each
>   post containing comments.

Answer (score 0):

In your question you wrote:

> In short, I should have both user_id and post_id when I call the addComment method.

Which is absolutely correct and no problem. You don't have to set these properties through a method like `$user->posts()->save($post)` - this is just a convenience method that does the job for you (see [`save($model)`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/HasOneOrMany.php#L246) and related [`setForeignAttributesForCreate($model)`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/HasOneOrMany.php#L306) in the framework code; these methods just set the foreign key property for you).

In fact, the following three ways to create a new post are interchangeable:

```
// what you did
$user->posts->save(
    new Post([
        'title' => 'Hello', 
        'body' => 'World!',
    ])
);

// equivalent
Post::create([
    'user_id' => \Auth::user()->id, // or \Auth::id()
    'title' => 'Hello',
    'body' => 'World!',
]);

// also equivalent
$post = new Post([
    'user_id' => \Auth::user()->id, // or \Auth::id()
    'title' => 'Hello',
    'body' => 'World!',
]);
$post->save();
```

When storing a new comment, you will most likely have a controller like this, because a comment always belongs to a post and you therefore will need a reference of the post:

```
class CommentsController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth')->except(['index', 'show']);
    }

    public function store(Post $post)
    {
        $comment = new Comment(request(['body']));
        $comment->user_id = \Auth::user()->id;
        $comment->post_id = $post->id;
        $comment->save();
    }
}
```

You could also abbreviate it and write:

```
Comment::create(
    array_merge(request(['body']), ['user_id' => \Auth::id(), 'post_id' => $post->id])
);
```